# SQL : strange behavior, deleting last related row on child table deletes row on father table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have the following tFather and tChild tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tChild', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.tChild

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tFather', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.tFather


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tFather](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [fld1] [varchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tFather] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tChild](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tFather_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [fld1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tChild] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tChild]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tChild_tFather] FOREIGN KEY([tFather_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tFather] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tChild] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tChild_tFather]
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.tFather (ID, fld1) VALUES ('1', 'a')

INSERT INTO dbo.tChild (tFather_ID, fld1) VALUES ('1', 'X')
INSERT INTO dbo.tChild (tFather_ID, fld1) VALUES ('1', 'Y')
INSERT INTO dbo.tChild (tFather_ID, fld1) VALUES ('1', 'Z')

SELECT * FROM dbo.tFather

ID | fld1
---------
 1 | a

SELECT * FROM dbo.tChild

ID | tFather_ID | fld1
----------------------
 1 |          1 | X
 2 |          1 | Y
 3 |          1 | Z
```

so far so good !
now when i delete a row from tFather, all the rows are deleted from tChild normally because of the cascade delete / update

the problem is when i delete rows from the tChild everything goes normally until i delete the last row and then the row in tFather is also deleted, which is very strange.

i have many related tables in the same database and they behave normally, ( no record is deleted in tFather when records are deleted in tChild ( table names are symbolic so you can understand the relationship type ) )

lets test the behavior:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.tChild WHERE ID='3'

SELECT * FROM dbo.tFather

ID | fld1
---------
 1 | a

SELECT * FROM dbo.tChild

ID | tFather_ID | fld1
----------------------
 1 |          1 | X
 2 |          1 | Y


DELETE FROM dbo.tChild WHERE ID='2'

SELECT * FROM dbo.tFather

ID | fld1
---------
 1 | a

SELECT * FROM dbo.tChild

ID | tFather_ID | fld1
----------------------
 1 |          1 | X


DELETE FROM dbo.tChild WHERE ID='1'

SELECT * FROM dbo.tFather

ID | fld1
---------
          << - HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!! NO ROWS !!!!!

SELECT * FROM dbo.tChild

ID | tFather_ID | fld1
----------------------
```

what could cause such behavior ?

any suggestion would be great

thank you

Comment: Tried your code on SQL 2008 R2 and it behaves perfectly. Data from the Father table is not getting deleted

Comment: I would guess at a trigger that you've not shown us.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : there are no triggers on any of those tables ! triggers were the first thing came to my mind.

Comment: the strangest thing is that tFather table exists over 3 years, tChild was created a week ago, and today i noticed the problem.

Comment: try the final delete from within a transaction, and do the select on the parent before committing. begin tran/delete/select.

Comment: i have tried every transaction combination but the behavior remain the same !

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is something to do with ON UPDATE CASCADE, and  ON DELETE CASCADE. However the code you have presented works fine and the Cascading works as it should i.e. if you delete the father all its children get deleted.